# Confused on house 'this' works with anonymous functions and const

Tags: javascript, object, this

I have the following code

```
const name = 'Jordan'

const myObj = {
  getName: function() {
    return this.name
  },
  getNameAnonymous: () => {
    return this.name
  }

}

console.log(myObj.getName())
console.log(myObj.getNameAnonymous())
```

When running, `getName` returns `undefined` and `getNameAnonymous` returns `"result"` (when I run it in JSFiddle but when I run it with Node I get `undefined`)

From what I understand `this` inside of arrow functions inside of objects is bound to the parent scope, so why doesn't `getNameAnonymous` return `Jordan`? And why does `getName` return `undefined` instead of a ReferenceError?

Comment: In browser environment a top level `var` becomes a property of `window` but that is not true for a `const`. In no environment will you access that const using `this`. It would help if you explained what you are wanting to accomplish here

Comment: Also worth noting that `window` has  a default `name` property that is empty string but is also assignable. It seems that jsfiddle is assigning the name of the iframe output page window as "result"

Comment: Ohhh. I see. So, because in the case of the arrow function `this` is bound to the `global` object, `name` is undefined because const variables do not get attached to the `global` object (`global` being `window` in the browser)

Comment: Yes and in browser case the window global actually has a `name` property. In jsfiddle run `console.log(window.name)` and it outputs `"result"`

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but how come I can do `window.fhjdgjfdgjhfd` and it will be undefined instead of throwing a ReferenceError?

Comment: Javascript doesn't error on properties of an actual object that don't exist. Note that if you open console on this page and log `wiindow.name` it is not undefined but rather an empty string